Text renders once and then it disappears within div (textContent) in HTML
I am currently trying to spawn HTML, CSS, JS, and firebase code within dangerouselySetInnerHTML, and the text successfully renders within avatar-initials textContent (initials) for a millisecond, and then it disappears. This also applies to fullName and email, which are in the menu list (render for a millisecond and then disappear). The HTML, CSS, and JS code is rendered in Next JS. I tried to remove useEffect and put htmlCode outside of the function, remove return, but none of those methods worked. I also previously put in an if statement to check for if (document.getElementById('avatar-initials').textContent == "") then change otherwise don't, but that also did not work. On the left is picture which spawns for a millisecond on the right is the picture that spawns afterward. If you need more information please let me know. Thank you in advance!


const NavBar = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load Firebase SDK scripts
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

const script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-firestore-compat.js";
script2.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script2);

script.onload = () => {
  script2.onload = () => {
    const scriptInit = document.createElement('script');
    scriptInit.innerHTML = `
      // Check if Firebase has already been initialized
      if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyBJUBPWGwmNfPa127y42YfUSrYcv63Jh3A",
          authDomain: "innovatex-c12c6.firebaseapp.com",
          projectId: "innovatex-c12c6",
          storageBucket: "innovatex-c12c6.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "837977074704",
          appId: "1:837977074704:web:ad488537707338cdae2e95",
          measurementId: "G-EP0JK2ETP7",
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      }

      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Fetch user data from Firestore
      db.collection("users").doc(localStorage.getItem("id")).get().then((val) => {
      const fullName = val.get("fullName");
      const email = val.get("email");
      const companyId = val.get("company");
      document.getElementById('full-name').innerText = fullName;
      document.getElementById('email').innerText = email;

      console.log(fullName)
      console.log(email)

      const initials = fullName.split(' ').map((name, index, arr) => {
        if (index === 0 || index === arr.length - 1) {
          return name.charAt(0);
        }
        return '';
      }).join('');
      document.getElementById('avatar-initials').textContent = initials;

      if (companyId) {
        db.collection('companies').doc(companyId).get().then((doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            const employees = doc.data().activeEmployees || {};
            window.employees = employees;
          }
        });
      }
    });

      function navigateTo(url) {
        window.location.href = url;
      }

      function handleSearchQueryChange(event) {
        const searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        if (searchQuery) {
          const filteredEmployees = Object.keys(window.employees).filter((key) =>
            window.employees[key].fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
          );
          showDropdown(true, filteredEmployees);
        } else {
          showDropdown(false, []);
        }
      }

      function showDropdown(show, filteredEmployees) {
        const dropdown = document.getElementById('search-dropdown');
        if (show) {
          dropdown.style.display = 'flex';
          dropdown.innerHTML = filteredEmployees
            .map(
              (userId) => 
                \`<button onclick="navigateTo('/c/view/' + '\${userId}')">\${window.employees[userId].fullName}</button>\`
            )
            .join('');
        } else {
          dropdown.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      function toggleCalculatorPopover() {
        const popover = document.getElementById('calculator-popover');
        popover.style.display = popover.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
      }

      function toggleMenu() {
        const menuList = document.getElementById('menu-list');
        menuList.style.display = menuList.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
      }

      async function logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('id');
        window.location.href = '/';
        alert('Logout Successful...');
        await firebase.auth().signOut()
      }

      // Calculator functionality
      let input = '';
      let result = '';

      function handleButtonClick(value) {
        input += value;
        document.getElementById('calculator-input').value = input;
      }

      function handleClear() {
        input = '';
        result = '';
        document.getElementById('calculator-input').value = '';
        document.getElementById('calculator-result').value = '';
      }

      function handleCalculate() {
        try {
          const evaluatedResult = evaluateExpression(input);
          result = evaluatedResult;
          document.getElementById('calculator-result').value = result;
        } catch (error) {
          document.getElementById('calculator-result').value = 'Error';
        }
      }

      function evaluateExpression(expr) {
        const sanitizedExpr = expr
          .replace(/\\^/g, '**')
          .replace(/\\|([^|]+)\\|/g, 'Math.abs($1)');
        return Function(\`'use strict'; return (\${sanitizedExpr})\`)();
      }

      function handleInputChange(event) {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const validChars = '0123456789+-*/^().|';
        let sanitizedValue = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
          if (validChars.includes(value[i])) {
            sanitizedValue += value[i];
          }
        }
        input = sanitizedValue;
        event.target.value = sanitizedValue;
      }

      function handleKeyPress(event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
          handleCalculate();
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        const menuList = document.getElementById('menu-list');
        // const calculatorPopover = document.getElementById('calculator-popover');
        if (!event.target.closest('#menu-list') && !event.target.closest('#avatar-initials')) {
          menuList.style.display = 'none';
        }
        // if (!event.target.closest('#calculator-popover') && !event.target.closest('.calculator-button')) {
        //   calculatorPopover.style.display = 'none';
        // }
      });

      document.getElementById('calculator-input').addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
      
      document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener('blur', function() {
        showDropdown(false, []);
      });

      document.getElementById('calculator-popover').addEventListener('blur', function() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
      });

    `;
    document.body.appendChild(scriptInit);
  };
};

return () => {
  document.body.removeChild(script);
  document.body.removeChild(script2);
};


}, []);



console.log('once')
  const htmlCode = `
    <style>
      .sidebar {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 80px;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        background-color: #000000;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 5px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 85px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        left: 8px;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 8px;
      }
      .hover-text {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .hover-text .hover-content {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 70px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: -50%;
        left: 100%;
        margin-left: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s;
        font-size: 9pt;
      }
      .hover-text:hover .hover-content {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      .icon-button {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }
      .icon-button:hover {
        background-color: #a0a0a0;
      }
      .icon-button img {
        filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
      }
      .divider {
        margin-bottom: 14px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        border-color: #dcdcdc;
        width: 60%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
      }
      .navbar {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 4px 5px;
        background-color: #000000;
        position: fixed;
        top: 3px;
        left: 8px;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      .search-box {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .search-box input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        autocomplete: off;
      }
      .search-dropdown {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 8px;
        z-index: 3;
      }
      .search-dropdown button {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .search-dropdown button:hover {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
      }
      .avatar-menu {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 8px;
        direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 3px;
      }
      .avatar-menu button {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .avatar-initials {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: purple;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 14pt;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: 1.5px solid white;
      }
        .avatar-initials:hover {
          opacity:0.85;
        }
      .menu-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: left;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 250px; /* Increased width */
      }
      .menu-item {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .menu-item:hover {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
      }
      .popover-content {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 75px;
        right: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .popover-header {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 16pt;
        color: #000000;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .popover-close-button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      .popover-close-button:hover {
        background-color: #dfdfdf;
      }
      .calculator-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .calculator-input,
      .calculator-result {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
      }
      .calculator-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        gap: 10px;
      }
      .calculator-button {
        background-color: #b0b0b0;
        border: none;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .calculator-button:hover {
        background-color: #a0a0a0;
      }
      .calculator-clear {
        grid-column: span 4;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
      }
      .calculator {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #2D3748;
        border-radius: 0.375rem;
        padding: 1.25rem;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        background-color: #2D3748;
      }
      .calculator input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.75rem;
        margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
        border-radius: 0.375rem;
        background-color: #2A2F45;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        text-align: right;
        border: none;
      }
      .calculator-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        gap: 0.75rem;
      }
      .calculator-button {
        padding: 0.75rem;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        border-radius: 0.375rem;
        background-color: #319795;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .calculator-button-clear {
        grid-column: span 4;
        background-color: #E53E3E;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button style="margin-top: 8px" class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/main')">
            <img src="/home.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">Home</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/todolist/overview')">
            <img src="/todolist.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">To-Do List</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/applicantTracking/overall')">
            <img src="/ats.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">ATS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/forum/overall')">
            <img src="/forum.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">Public Forum</span>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/timeTracker/overall')">
            <img src="/timeTracker.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">Time Tracker</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/timeOff/overall')">
            <img src="/timeOff2.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">Time Off</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/benefits/overall')">
            <img src="/benefits.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">Benefits</span>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/payroll/overview')">
            <img src="/payroll.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">Payroll</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-text">
          <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/customize')">
            <img src="/customize.png" width="25" height="25" />
          </button>
          <span class="hover-content">Customize</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 5px;">
          <button style="color: white; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; font-family: Montserrat; background-color: transparent; border: none; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: 800; cursor: pointer;" onclick="navigateTo('/c/main')">
            <i>I</i>
          </button>
          <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for a co-worker" autocomplete="off" oninput="handleSearchQueryChange(event)" />
            <div id="search-dropdown" class="search-dropdown" style="display: none;">
              <!-- Dropdown content will be injected here -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="avatar-menu">
          <div class="hover-text">
            <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/employees')">
              <img src="/people.png" width="25" height="25" />
            </button>
            <span class="hover-content">Employees</span>
          </div>
          <div class="hover-text">
            <button class="icon-button" onclick="navigateTo('/c/privateToDo')">
              <img src="/toDo.png" width="25" height="25" />
            </button>
            <span class="hover-content">Private To-Do List</span>
          </div>
          <div class="hover-text">
            <button class="icon-button" onclick="toggleCalculatorPopover()">
              <img src="/calculator.png" width="25" height="25" />
            </button>
            <span class="hover-content">Calculator</span>
          </div>
          <a href="/c/feedback" style="color: white; font-weight: 800; text-decoration: none; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 5px;">FEEDBACK</a>
          <a href="/c/help" style="color: white; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 8px;"><img src="/info.png" width="25" height="25;" /></a>
          <div style="margin-left: 14px; margin-right: 22px;">
            <button onclick="toggleMenu()">
              <div id="avatar-initials" class="avatar-initials"></div>
            </button>
            <div id="menu-list" class="menu-list" style="display: none;">
              <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: left; justify-content: center; padding: 10px;">
                <span id="full-name" style="font-size: 12pt; font-weight: 700; color: #000000;"></span>
                <span id="email" style="font-size: 10pt; color: gray;"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item" onclick="logout()">
                <img src="/logout.png" width="25" height="25" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="calculator-popover" class="popover-content" style="display: none; z-index: 9999999;" tabindex="0">
        <button class="popover-close-button" onclick="toggleCalculatorPopover()" style="font-weight: 900; font-size: 16pt"><img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" src="/close.png"></button>
        <div class="calculator" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 40px">
          <input id="calculator-input" placeholder="0" oninput="handleInputChange(event)" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)">
          <input id="calculator-result" placeholder="Result" readonly>
          <div class="calculator-grid">
            ${["7", "8", "9", "/"].map(value => `
              <button class="calculator-button" onclick="handleButtonClick('${value}')">${value}</button>
            `).join('')}
            ${["4", "5", "6", "*"].map(value => `
              <button class="calculator-button" onclick="handleButtonClick('${value}')">${value}</button>
            `).join('')}
            ${["1", "2", "3", "-"].map(value => `
              <button class="calculator-button" onclick="handleButtonClick('${value}')">${value}</button>
            `).join('')}
            ${["0", ".", "(", ")"].map(value => `
              <button class="calculator-button" onclick="handleButtonClick('${value}')">${value}</button>
            `).join('')}
            ${["+", "="].map(value => `
              <button class="calculator-button" onclick="${value === '=' ? 'handleCalculate()' : `handleButtonClick('${value}')`}">${value}</button>
            `).join('')}
            <button class="calculator-button" onclick="handleButtonClick('^')">^</button>
            <button class="calculator-button" onclick="handleButtonClick('|')">|</button>
            <button class="calculator-button calculator-button-clear" onclick="handleClear()">Clear</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  return (
    <VStack spacing={4} align="center" marginBottom="5vh">
      {/* <Box width="100%" maxW="400px" borderWidth="1px" borderRadius="lg" p={5} boxShadow="lg" backgroundColor="gray.700"> */}
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlCode }} />
      {/* </Box> */}
    </VStack>
  );
};


Sorry but I cried in react. To the problem: write the script in the react way, Define the functions, create onClick handlers, use a state for the list of avatars etc. Then render them in the react way.
